# AWS CloudFormation error: "Route did not stabilize in expected time"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to deploy a CloudFormation template from an AWS workshop - https://emr-developer-experience.workshop.aws/how-to-start/self-paced/cloudformation.html.

The CF template is located at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/stacks/new?stackName=EMR-Dev-Exp-Workshop&templateURL=https://aws-data-analytics-workshops.s3.amazonaws.com/emr-dev-exp-workshop/cfn/emr-dev-exp.template

This CF template creates a new VPC with all the required networking components as well as various services such as EMR, EMR Studio, Service Catalog, etc.

I am from a data background and I am having a hard time debugging this CF template.

Basically, it fails when creating the logical ID "VPCGatewayAttachment" with the error message "Route did not stabilize in expected time". A KB article from AWS (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-route-did-not-stabilize/) has some information, but I don't think I really understand the outlined solution.

Appreciate any help.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found this article for you on AWS' Knowledge Center https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-route-did-not-stabilize/ As the article mentions I would also have a look at the AWS CloudTrail Event History and investigate any potential errors and root causes. When browsing the Event History, I personally like enabling the error codes (you can do that if you press the gear icon) which allow me to quickly detect events that have failed.

Comment: Thanks. I came across that article, but I didn't really understand their suggestion. I will look at CloudTrail Event History and see if it helps.